# Using the `.every` array method how do I write a function that determines whether every number in an array is a square number?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where I need to write a function that determines whether every number in an array is a square number, specifically using the `.every` method. Though, I'm not too sure how to approach it.

This was the starting code provided

```
function positiveProduct(array) {

}
```

The problem

```
describe('allSquare', () => {
  it('should check if all numbers are square', () => {
    expect(allSquare([81, 9, 16])).to.be.true
    expect(allSquare([10, 50, 8])).to.be.false
  })
})
```

The function should convert strings to numbers, and should only return a positive number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your issue with this ? How to determine if a number is a square number, or how to use .every method ?

Anyway, that's how you could do it :

```
function positiveProduct(numbers) {
  return numbers.every(number => number > 0 && Math.sqrt(number) % 1 === 0)
}
```

If you're not familiar with ES6 arrow functions, you can also do this :

```
function positiveProduct(numbers) {
  return numbers.every(function(number) {
    return number > 0 && Math.sqrt(number) % 1 === 0
  })
}
```

Comment: How to use .every method. Looking at your solution, I see that I was over complicating it in my head, a lot.

Comment: Basically, .every is like .forEach. The callback passed as an argument to .every method will be called on each item and has to return true or false. If the callback returned true on each turn, .every will return true, otherwise false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every